# How to read the content of the PDF file which is uploaded into Google Drive?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to read the content of the PDF file which is uploaded into google drive. The content should be in a human readable format, not in binary format. Right now I'm using google drive API to read the content but unable to do that.

```
 $fileId = $request['thesis_google_id'];
    $response = $service->files->get($fileId,   array(
    'alt' => 'media'));
    $content = $response->getBody()->read(2024);
```

Answer (score 1):

The core functionality of the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) is to download and upload files in Google Drive. This API does not give you the ability to read anything it just stores the files for you and allows you to download them.

The [Google Docs api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview) does give you access to read and write files but i suspect it only supports google docs format files not PDF.

You will need to download the file locally then use some form of PDF reader for PHP to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Files: export` method provided by the [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) to get the contents of a PDF file. The export method for `.pdf` files won’t return images, but all text in the file can be exported into a human readable format. The supported MIME Types that you can export to are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents).

In PHP, you can achieve this with the following code:

```
$fileId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$response = $service->files->export($fileId, 'MIMEType', array(
    'alt' => 'media'));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Your application will need at least read permissions for Google Docs in order to do this, and should include the query parameter `alt=media`.

Comment: @Rata Guillermo I'm using this method, but still not able to read the content of my Google Drive PDF file. I'm using the following scope for my project. Please check once and let me know if anything I'm missing.
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

Comment: Are you getting an error trying to run the code, and if so what is it? Also make sure you change `'MIMEType'` in the `export` method to the MIMEType you want, in this case `'application/pdf'`.

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but content is also not getting. I changed MIMEType to application/pdf.

Comment: What is the value of `content` after you call `getContents()`?